# Create LogicApp and API Connections ARM Template using DotNet SDK

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk, dotnet-sdk

I have created **Azure Logic App** using **Dot.Net SDK**. Logic App created successfully but for Trigger and Action i want to use **existing Connector**. I have manually created connector to Azur Portal. I am passing that Connector's APIConnection or Id to request json but it will not connect to that connector. I mean Logic App is created without any connectors.

Below is my Request Json.

---

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "defaultValue": {
                "smtp": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/680cf604-e2e7-4a14-9724-a26c35c573ff/resourceGroups/logicapp_flow_rnd/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/smtp",
                    "connectionName": "smtp",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/680cf604-e2e7-4a14-9724-a26c35c573ff/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westindia/managedApis/smtp"
                },
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/680cf604-e2e7-4a14-9724-a26c35c573ff/resourceGroups/logicapp_flow_rnd/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/680cf604-e2e7-4a14-9724-a26c35c573ff/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westindia/managedApis/sql"
                }
            },
            "type": "Object"
        }
    },
    "triggers": {
        "When_an_item_is_created": {
            "inputs": {
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/datasets/default/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('LogicAppTable1'))}/onnewitems"
            },
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']",
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        }
    },
    "actions": {
        "Send_Email": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "Body": "New Item Created - @{triggerBody()?['Id']}",
                    "From": "info@logicappdemo.com",
                    "Subject": "LogicAppDemo - New Item Created",
                    "To": "hitesh.vaghasiya@softwebsolutions.com"
                },
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['smtp']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "post",
                "path": "/SendEmailV2"
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "ApiConnection"
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is the screen shot from Azur portal. Here you can see that Logic App is created successfully but without Connector.

[Azure Portal Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG4l3.png)

Please Suggest,

Thanks

Comment: can you not create the logic app directly from the portal ?

Comment: Yes, We can but we have to create it from DotNet SDK.

Thanks

Comment: @HITESHKUMARVAGHASIYA have you figured it out? I am also having the same problem, I am thinking about doing all the connector related stuff in an attached Azure Function, but if you have figured out something without any external tool/tech I'd be interested to know.

Answer (score 3):

Hi @HITESHKUMARVAGHASIYA, if you don't have Visual Studio (which is the simplest and easiest option), then you can rely on other alternatives

For the SQL API Connection, you can use [this template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-logic-app-sql-proc/azuredeploy.json). Below I show the extract for the SQL API Connection,

```
{   
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "name": "[parameters('sqlConnectionName')]",
  "properties": {
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat(subscription().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('location'), '/managedApis/sql')]"
    },
    "displayName": "sql_connection",
    "parameterValues": {
      "server": "[parameters('sqlServer')]",
      "database": "[parameters('sqlDatabase')]",
      "authType": "windows",
      "username": "[parameters('sqlUser')]",
      "password": "[parameters('sqlPassword')]"
    }
  }
},
```

To create the SMTP API Connection, I haven't seen a sample, but you could get the ARM definition with Azure CLI (e.g. https://shell.azure.com) and then get the definition of your resource, e.g.

```
az resource show --ids /subscriptions/680cf604-e2e7-4a14-9724-a26c35c573ff/resourceGroups/logicapp_flow_rnd/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/smtp
```

That would give you a starting point to craft your own ARM Template.

Another option is to use PowerShell Template Generator from Jeff Hollan, which I believe exports the API Connections as well.

https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppTemplateCreator

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. Do you know how and using with class and method we can create SQL API Connection using DotNet SDK.

Answer (score 1):

We also could design our logic app with [Azure Logic Apps Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VinaySinghMSFT.AzureLogicAppsToolsforVisualStudio-18551) locally. Sign in with our Azure Account, then we could design it as Azure portal. We also could swith view or code interface. We could do that easily with [Azure Logic Apps Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VinaySinghMSFT.AzureLogicAppsToolsforVisualStudio-18551).
For more detail information please refer to [Build and Deploy Logic Apps in Visual Studio](https://github.com/wbuchwalter/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-deploy-from-vs.md).

I test it using a servicebus connection, it works correctly after publish to Azure

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually as per our current requirement we have to create LogicApp workflow using DotNet SDK.

Comment: @HITESHKUMARVAGHASIYA Would you mind sharing more information about using Dotnet SDK, if there is  detail steps to use the Dotnet SDK will be helpful? In my case, if I want to get the code, I just need to change it to the code view and we also could get the code in the deploy.json file. Then I could get the request json as you metioned.